# Why does such a lamp and two battery circuit not work?

Tags: basic

Assume I have a lamp and I connect one side to the + pole of one battery, and then the other side to the - pole of another battery (say two batteries of 1.5V). The remaining - and + poles are not connected.

So there is a potential difference between across the lamp, but why does it not turn on? It seems to contradict the basic law of electricity.

Note: I am a newbie in electronics/electricty.

Comment: "I am a newbie in electronics/electricty." Kirchoff's Laws might be a good place to start.

Answer (score 7):

> Why does such circuit not work?

It's not a circuit to begin with since there is no closed path around which charge can flow through the lamp.

Let's try a different route to see this result.  To make your 'circuit' an actual circuit, place a resistor between the *"remaining - and + poles"* as so

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQbCAk.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Using elementary circuit laws, we can find the potential difference across the lamp to be

$$V_{\mathrm{lamp1}} = (6\:\mathrm{V} + 6\:\mathrm{V})\cdot \frac{100}{R_1 + 100}$$

So, for example, if \$R_1 = 0\:\Omega\$ then

$$V_{\mathrm{lamp1}} = 12\:\mathrm{V} \cdot \frac{100}{0 + 100} = 12\:\mathrm{V}$$

But, as the resistance of \$R_1\$ is increased, the potential difference across the lamp *must* decrease.

For example, if \$R_1 = 1\: \mathrm{M\Omega}\$, then

$$V_{\mathrm{lamp1}} = 12\:\mathrm{V} \frac{100}{1,000,000 + 100} =  0.012 \: \mathrm{V}$$

Setting \$R_1 = \infty\$ is equivalent to specifying that the *"- and + poles are not connected"*.

In that case the potential difference across the lamp is

$$V_{\mathrm{lamp1}} = 12\:\mathrm{V} \frac{100}{\infty + 100} =  0 \: \mathrm{V}$$

in contradiction to the claim *"So there is a potential difference between across the lamp"*.  In fact, there is *no* potential difference across the lamp and, as stated earlier, it is for the simple reason that there is no closed path around which charge can flow through the lamp.

Comment: Since the impedance of your R1 **can't** be infinite (although it **is** very large), there must be **some** miniscule charge flowing in the circuit and, therefore, some potential across the lamp.

Comment: @EMFields, I have given your comment precisely the amount of consideration it is due.

Comment: Hmm... I wasn't aware that  Argumentum ad hominem  was  acceptable as a substitute for facts around here, and your logic is weak in that you've chosen to comment on what you claim is unworthy of consideration. ;) Referring to your diagram, though,  since BAT1 plus and BAT2 minus are connected through LAMP1, then there **must** exist a potential difference between BAT1 minus and BAT2 plus through which charge flows.  Not very much, mind you, but since the impedance/resistance of the medium connecting BAT1 minus and BAT2 plus isn't infinite, then an infinitesimal charge must flow through LAMP1

Comment: @EMFields, a statement of fact does not make an *"Argumentum ad hominem"*.  I stated a fact and that fact is precisely this:  I do not value your comment (original or follow-up).

Comment: You didn't state that, you snidely alluded to it with a prissy little  air of arrogance about you. More to the point, you preferred to attack me personally instead of pointing out why you disagree with my comment(s),  which is precisely argumentum ad hominem.  You've also chosen to escalate the argument because, in my opinion, you can't refute the fact that the impedance between BAT1 minus and BAT2 plus (R1 in your drawing) isn't infinite and, consequently, are trying to kill the messenger instead of merely owning up to your error.  If you'd like the last word, take it; I'm done with this...

Comment: @EMFields, the fact that I don't find your comment(s) remotely interesting is, on my view, hardly an attack on you personally.  That you don't agree with my answer does not compel me to find your disagreement interesting or to find value in arguing with you.

Comment: @EMFields, actually, from a nodal analysis perspective (which is what we're talking about), R1 is *precisely* equal to infinity. If you want to be pedantic and talk about **actual** charge flowing — however minuscule — you should know that KVL and KCL can't be used to analyze such systems, as those rules assume electric fields do not interact with each other. You're being pedantic but not even doing it correctly. And while you're allowed to be pedantic on the Internet, it's not helpful to beginners to ask them to consider femtoamp EM fields when they're learning basic circuit theory.

Answer (score 3):

The potential difference is only *between* the terminals of *each* battery.

There is no "global" potential difference.

This is why a circuit *must* be complete in some manner for current to flow.

Answer (score 1):

Since the resistance of the lamp is vanishingly small compared to the resistance between the  unconnected battery terminals, the potential difference across the lamp will be vanishingly small as well, with largely all of the drop occurring across the huge resistance of the medium separating the "unconnected " terminals.

That resistance will be so large that it'll limit the flow of charge through the circuit to a value so low that it couldn't possibly light the lamp.